# What are the advantages of TWeakObjectPtr automatic nulling?

Tags: c++, unreal, unreal-5

When you use `TWeakObjectPtr` to hold an `Actor` reference then the pointer variable is automatically nulled for you by GC when the `Actor` is destroyed. Is there any meaningful advantage of this?

If you use `IsValid` in your pointer validation then it doesnt matter if the pointer is `nullptr` or not when `Actor` is already destroyed.